# Android 2.1 gridview not displayed

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to display some images in a grid view. My code works for android 2.2 and 2.3, but not in 2.1

In android 2.1 the grid is always empty/invisible.

The code I use for the grid view is this one:

```
gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.level_select);
gridview.setAdapter(new LevelImagesAdapter(this, levelsCount,
            maxLevel, listener));
gridview.invalidate();
```

The LevelImagesAdapter is:

```
public class LevelImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    private Context mContext;
    private int count;
    private int maxLevel;

    public LevelImagesAdapter(Context c, int maxLevel, int count, View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.count = count;
        this.maxLevel = maxLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new Button(mContext);
            view.setOnClickListener(listener);
            view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.setPadding(5, 5, 5,5);
        }
        else {
            view = (Button) convertView;
        }

        if (position <= maxLevel) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level_unlock);
            view.setText((position + 1) + "");
            view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.setTextSize(16.0f);
        }
        else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level_lock);
            view.setText("");
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

As far as I can tell, the adapter is created, but the getView method is never called.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried manually calling notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: by "As far as I can tell, the adapter is created, but the getView method is never called." - did you put a `Log.d` in there and run it and check `LogCat` to make sure its not being called? Or use debug in some way?

Comment: Yes, I've put a Log.v in the method and it is never called.

Comment: Could you try to return something other than `null` in `getItem()`?

Comment: I think the @Override over the `getView` method is not required.. Try after removing it.. Remove every other @override if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @gulyan Your code is working fine at my end with Android 2.1 (API 7).

Answer (score 6):

Your `getItem(position)` must return something other than `NULL`

Make sure `getCount()` is returning a non-zero number.

Check and make sure you have your GridView layout parameters set to `fill_parent` in your layout and not `match_parent` Lower API levels don't support `match_parent` so `fill_parent` is backwardly compatible.  The GridView could be hidden and it won't call `getView` in that case.

Comment: getCount() is not 0; the layout parameters must be wrap_content for my needs; will try with getItem

Comment: wrap_content will have problems if the number of items you are displaying is larger than the viewable area.  Essentially if you use wrap_content for the height or width of the grid it will always create getCount() number of items which subverts the whole benefits of using a GridView in the first place.  You're guaranteed to take up the maximum amount memory needed to display all of the items.  Plus wrap_content can produce the problem your seeing if the view items within are marked fill_parent/match_parent.

Comment: If you use wrap_content on the width you won't get any wrapping on the grid.  It'll all be just one row of getCount() items long.

Comment: I've changed the width to android:layout_width="fill_parent", same problem

Comment: I'm talking about the height.  If nothing is being displayed it might be because there is no height.  mark the height fill_parent just to see if it is hidden.